# how to create trigger in mysql for insert data into table

Tags: mysql

```
Leave_applied_table:

leave_applied_id  employee_id   status    start_date       end_date_session   hours
1                    345           1      2016-6-25          2016-8-25        16

Leave_actula_table:

leave_applied_id    leave_type_id    hours   created_at
345                  2                  16      2016-7-25
345                  2                  16      2016-7-25 
345                  2                 16       2016-7-25


Leave_approval_table:
leave_approval_id      leave_applied_id   manger_id    status
56                        345               125           1
```

this is my three table i have to create triggger like when i insert in to Leave_applied  then in leave_actual table three row should insert and in leave_approval_table  in entry should come as given data in table please suggest me how to write query for this how to create trigger i  am new in one this please suggest me for give issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Leave_applied_table FOR EACH ROW
begin
     insert into Leave_actula_table (Leave_actula_table.leave_applied_id,and so ON....) values(new.employee_id,new.leave_type_id) ;

     insert into Leave_approval_table (Leave_approval_table.leave_applied_id, and so on....) values (new.employee_id and so on;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope it helps you as a guide..

Comment: OK wait let me try

Comment: do you want to show your triigger? do it like this select * from information_schema.`TRIGGERS`

Comment: like suppose in feature if i want to edit that trigger then how i will seee and edit it will some where save that trigger code?

Comment: use that above and run it in your workbench.. then find the action_ statement column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118175/discussion-between-research-development-and-reds).